# How can I replace this connection? (sprinkler system)

Tags: leak, sprinkler-system, connectors

So this connection sprung a leak sometime over the winter, I need to add tape to it or replace the connector.  How can I get the metal loops off?  They aren't the kind that has a screw to loosen/tighten[image]

[image]

Comment: It’s crimp on, you just destroy them to remove.  You can replace with the screw type.

Comment: How do I get them off though?

Comment: Sometime you can get ahold of the joint with channelocks and twist and they release... other times it’s more painful.  Worst case use a dremel tool and cut them off.

Comment: they are probably one of these .... https://www.amazon.com/421376-STAINLESS-STEEL-CRIMP-RING/dp/B003OL6BXW .... cut off the raised tab

Comment: Sometimes you just cut the pipe, lose an inch,  replace the fitting be done with it.

Comment: Dremel is a good idea. I don't think I can afford to lose an inch unless I add another connector

Comment: Depends on where the leak is. Under the clamp? The connector? The pipe? You may want to cut the inch off and start form there.

Comment: It's where the plastic connector meets the metal pipe

Comment: Don't worry about losing an inch. You can always splice in another horizontal piece.